# How to wrap dynamically created textviews in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating various textviews inside a linear layout (lay). I want that when the textview reach out of the screen then that textview automatically jump on the next line instead of out of the screen. I am a beginner in android and not getting how to achieve it.

Here is my code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < string.size(); i++) {
         final TextView txt = new TextView(con);
         txt.setText(string.get(i));
         lay.addView(txt);   
        }
```

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: Sorry @Jitendraramoliya its not working in my case.

Comment: What is your text to set in textView?

Comment: Its a value from an array(string) like String string[]={"a","b"............};

Comment: @Sumit see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
TextView txt = new TextView(context);
txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void populateViews(LinearLayout linearLayout, ArrayList<TextView> views, View extraView)
{
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    float mWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    extraView.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    int maxWidth = (int) mWidth - extraView.getMeasuredWidth() - 10;

    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
    LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    newLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    int widthSoFar = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
    {
        LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        LL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        views.get(i).measure(0, 0);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(views.get(i).getMeasuredWidth(), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(10, 2, 10, 2);

        LL.addView(views.get(i), params);
        LL.measure(0, 0);
        widthSoFar += views.get(i).getMeasuredWidth();
        if (widthSoFar >= maxWidth)
        {
            linearLayout.addView(newLL);

            newLL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            newLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LL.getMeasuredWidth(), LL.getMeasuredHeight());
            newLL.addView(LL, params);
            widthSoFar = LL.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
        else
        {
            newLL.addView(LL);
        }
    }
    linearLayout.addView(newLL);
}
```

This method should be able to help you. I had made this method long back, so with a few modifications you should be able to use it. The first parameter is a `LinearLayout` which will be the base vertical linear layout which will act as the primary container for the views. The second parameter are the actual views you have to add. The third parameter in my case was an Image which I was using like a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this also.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < string.size(); i++) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = (View) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.Layout_Design, null);
            TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.some_text);
            txt.setText("for runtime change");
            layout.addView(view);
            // layout is linear layout in my case.
       }
```

**Layout_Design:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/some_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SOme Text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```